# Run an application as background process

Tags: java, windows

I have developed a Java application. I want to run it as a background process.
It should not be displayed as Running Application in task Manager, but it should be displayed in Processes List.
Help me out.
Regards,
Jigar

Answer (score 4):

I've edited your question since it's a pure windows issue.

I would suggest you to take a look at ways to [run your java application as a windows service](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0151.html).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Command Prompt option given by Rafael Roman, we can also schedule task through Control Panel -> Scheduled Tasks -> Add Schedued Task. For more info:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738106(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for complex solutions.

use the `at` commando and create a bat that runs your program.

type in any cmd windows:

```
at 10:00 c:\run_my_script.bat
```

remember to replace 10:00 to a time 1 minute after the current time of your machine